# OSGI Equinox with Hibernate JPA Setting up

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, osgi, equinox

I am setting up a simple example to persist one Person entity using Hibenate in an OSGI Equinox using eclipse. I read the official documentation in [Hibernate web site](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html_single/#osgi-unmanaged-jpa) but the examples use another frameworks and I dont know how many bundles I need and how to set up them.

Comment: The relevant part is in `HibernateUtils` class. On the other side: why don't you add those dependencies too? I have seen there some bundles from apache felix and some osgi specific imports: check this file for all imports: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.2/documentation/src/main/docbook/quickstart/tutorials/osgi/unmanaged-jpa/pom.xml

Comment: So I only need one bundle with the Hibernate jar files and this HibernateUtils class and adding all these bundles like required dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

After a few days trying to use hibernate in an Equinox Osgi, I get it. I created a thread in the Hibernate Forum so you can go there:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1029974&p=2473673#p2473673

Basically you need to do step by step, setting up every bundle that you need, and also updated to the Hibernate 4.3.0 version and take care with the order of your bundles in run time!!